# Partitions not showing on windows neither in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have installed `Ubuntu 14.04` along with the existing windows 8 ....

I have made three partitions of `/` , `/boot` and `swap`, but seems as it is not visible on windows neither on Ubuntu. What can do for visibility of these drives?

Answer (score 1):

Windows can't see the Ubuntu partition because Ubuntu's file system type is ext4. In the file manager Computer is the / partition and the swap and /boot is not for you to see. If you really need to see them, then install gparted.

Comment: You can also use "parted" in a terminal or gnome-disks in a GUI.